# Regexp pattern with any single character without white-spaces

Tags: java, regex

```
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".");
```

This pattern works for me in both cases:

1. when there is only one character
2. when there is only one character + a lot of white spaces (new lines, spaces)

How to change this to ignore white spaces? So valid is:

```
"a"
```

And not valid:

```
" a", "    a    ", "\n     a"
```

Comment: Use ['regex101'](https://regex101.com/r/4xLbCA/1) to test your regex.

Answer (score 3):

`\S` is "not a whitespace", so your regex could be something like this:

```
^\S$
```

Comment: `\S` is a shortcut for `^\s`. `\s` = whitespace character. `\S` = non-whitespace (`^\s)`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html

Comment: @Strikegently Isn't that what I said in my answer?

Comment: I was pointing out that there is `\s` (lowercase s) that means whitespace, and `\S` (uppercase S) that means not whitespace. Your pattern could be simplified to just use the lowercase instead of negating the uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

basic regex features:

- anchors `^`, `$` to ensure the character matched is the first and the last in input
- character set `[`..`]` to specify wanted characters or `[^`..`]` for unwanted characters

Note that in a string the backslashes have a special meaning and must be doubled to have a literal `\` in regex which has also a special meaning `\n` for new line character

```
 Pattern.compile("^[^ \\n]$");
```

Comment: I am trying to read only single character from user input in console, but any suggested pattern doesnt want to work for me

while (!scanner.hasNext(Pattern.compile("^[^ \\n]$"))) {
      scanner.nextLine();
    }

    return scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
if (str.matches("\\S"))  // don't need ^ and $ in the regex with matches()
```

or just

```
if (str.length() == 1 && !Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(0)))
```